# Creating Api controller in asp .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created controller called `ApiConroller` in MVC project. When I tried to run its `Index()` action method it returns the below error message:

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated
>   with it. The document tree is shown below.   No HTTP
>   resource was found that matches the request URI
>   'http://localhost:60000/api/index'.

Why it is returning xml file? How to make it return a view?

Comment: Web Api controllers don't normally return views. You're expected to return data, usually as XML or JSON.

Comment: @TiesonT. it is not a web api controller. I am creating normal mvc controller named as ApiController. I also tried to return `json` but it is giving the same error.

Comment: `/api/` is part of the default mapping for the Web Api routing. If you're not using Web Api, make sure you remove those maps (remove the WebApiConfig from your project and/or remove `WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)` from the Global.asax file). If you are using Web Api somewhere, you'll need to change the routing.

Comment: @TiesonT. I have removed those mappings as you have mentioned. Now its working. If you could post it as an answer I would accept your answer. Thank you for your quick response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/api/` is part of the default mapping for the Web Api routing, as shown here:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

If you're not using Web Api, make sure you remove those route maps by removing the WebApiConfig file from your project and/or removing `WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)` from the Global.asax file.

If you *are* using Web Api somewhere, you'll need to change the routing noted above.